# node / express REST API application - passing parameters to GET method

Tags: node.js, rest, express

**Background**

I'm writing a sample nodejs / express REST interface or API for the purposes of learning. I've created a new route called "emergency".

In the file I have the following code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        //var ip = req.params.ip;
        res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

When I start the application and navigate to http://myserver/tutorial1/emergency
everything works fine and I see the "respond with a resource" message.

**Goal**

I'd like my application to be able to accept parameters as well.  So fro example, when a user navigates to

```
 http://myserver/tutorial1/emergency
```

I want all emergency numbers to be queried and returned.  But they should also be able to do this:

```
 http://myserver/tutorial1/emergency/12345
```

and the system should query the database for emergency record 12345 and return the appropriate result set.

**Problem / Question**

In order to accommodate both types of GET queries, I've changed the code to look like this:

```
router.get('/id', function(req, res, next) {
        //var ip = req.params.ip;
        res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

Now when I run the application, and browse to

```
 http://myserver/tutorial1/emergency/12345
```

it works.  However, browsing to

```
  http://myserver/tutorial1/emergency
```

fails with a 404 error message.

Not Found

404

```
Error: Not Found
    at /var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/app.js:34:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
    at next (/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

Do I need to create two separate methods, one that accepts a parameter and one that doesn't?  (aka method overloads?)
Perhaps my understanding of REST is what's faulty.  Should a GET request look like :

```
 http://myserver/tutorial1/emergency
```

or should it always look like this:

```
 http://myserver/tutorial1/emergency/{id}
```

Maybe the proper way to do a GET for all records is something like this:

```
 http://myserver/tutorial1/emergency/all
```

I'm trying to google my question right now as well, but I'm having a hard time expressing it succinctly enough to get an accurate search result set.

**EDIT 1**

This is what my code looks like when I try to create two methods (and this works)

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        var id = req.params.id;
        console.log(id);
        res.send('got it');
});
```

But this just feels odd because I guess I'm used to other frameworks in other languages where the system can check for empty params so you just need one method. 
this is not a complaint!  just a comment that might explain why my brain is "expecting" the system to work a different way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Do I need to create two separate methods, one that accepts a parameter
>   and one that doesn't?

I'm guessing you posted this before even trying that?

The answer is yes.

Your route that accepts parameters should look like this:

```
app.get('/emergency/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('The id: ' + id);
});
```

Comment: no i have tried it.  but because i'm a node js noob, i'm questioning whether my approach is correct.  and I was also missing the ":" that you have here. If I have a routes/emergency.js file where all of this logic is in, do i actually need the 'emergency' in '/emergency/:id' that you have in your answer?  I don't think I do

Comment: The code in your edit is fine. I don't understand your second question in your comment. The two route approach is fine, its simple and it works.

Comment: Tom, please see "Edit 1" section in my original question

Comment: Not sure what else you want - Express isn't about the change how they approach routing because your brain expects the system to work differently.

Comment: lol.  Tom, i realize that.  I think you're missing the point of my question.  Because I'm inexperienced with the tool, I'm asking for validation of my current understanding of how i should use it.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. Its simple and it works, nothing else to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it is necessary to have two different functions that listen to each type of url.
This is because 
The url

```
http://localhost/example/abcd will get received in 
router.get('/example/:username',testFunction1);
```

whereas

```
http://localhost/example will be received in 
router.get('/example',testFunction2);
```

Refer to the article: http://codewhoop.com/article/Nodejs%20Getting%20parameters%20through%20GET%20method
for detailed explanation of procedure to fetch paramters through GET method in Nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure will it work or not you can try some thing like this

```
app.get('/emergency/:var(:id/|)', function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('The id: ' + id);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!  I gave it a try and it works when I just try without a parameter.  But when I pass a parm, it fails with a 404. If express / node isn't designed to work this way... it's ok.  I'm just trying to understand what the "right" way to design my application is.